# A Quartz job already exists with the name/group with spring mvc and camel

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

Hi I am getting the following exception

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route healthCheckRoute: Route(healthCheckRoute)[[From[quartz://healthCheck?cron={{sf... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: quartz://healthCheck?cron=0%2F30+*+*+*+*+%3F due to: A Quartz job already exists with the name/group: healthCheck/Camel
org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:182)
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:770)
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1914)
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1670)
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1544)
org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)
org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1512)
org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)
org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)
org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:301)
org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

this is happening when I deploy and start my spring mvc web app .Though the isolated test cases on the same work fine .Does anyone know about the issue.

Please HElp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like two Camel routes were configured using the same camelContext ID. Check their IDs and change them in case they are equal. Also check if you're not loading Camel context twice, as that would produce the same error.

Also take a look at this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5259

Comment: I have just one route healthcheckroute in my camel context but still getting that error .. This works fine when working with a test case but in spring MVC controller invocation the same causes an error

Comment: Check if you're not loading Camel context twice.

Comment: ya @Andres its loadin twice I get this                   'org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy
   
        Message:This CamelContext(salesForceInbound) will be registered using the name: salesForceInbound-1 due to clash with an existing name already registered in MBeanServer.

org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy
           Message:This CamelContext(salesForceInbound) will be registered using the name: salesForceInbound-2 due to clash with an existing name already registered in MBeanServer.'

Comment: There you have your two routes with the same id.

Comment: thanks @Andres figured put the issue it was due to multiple web application contexts I had and two of it reloaded the Camel Context twice silly mistake by me